# ORA-01870 trying to convert from date into timestamp with time zone

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

when the following PL/SQL anonymous block is run using SQL DEVELOPER on Oracle DB 11g

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    d_next_run_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string(
            calendar_string => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=15', 
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04/06/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            return_date_after => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            next_run_date => d_next_run_date
            );

    dbms_output.put_line(d_next_run_date);
END;
```

the following exception is thrown

```
ORA-01870: the intervals or datetimes are not mutually comparable
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 3599
ORA-06512: at line 4
01870. 00000 -  "the intervals or datetimes are not mutually comparable"
*Cause:    The intervals or datetimes are not mutually comparable.
*Action:   Specify a pair of intervals or datetimes that are mutually
           comparable.
```

I suspect the issue is related to timezone.

The exception is not thrown if the arguments are changed to the following (notice that I changed the value that is passed into parameter return_date_after)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    d_next_run_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string(
            calendar_string => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=15', 
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04/06/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            return_date_after => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/01/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            next_run_date => d_next_run_date
            );

    dbms_output.put_line(d_next_run_date);
END;
```

or if the arguments are changed to the following (again I changed the value that is passed into parameter return_date_after)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    d_next_run_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string(
            calendar_string => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=15', 
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04/06/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            return_date_after => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/06/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
            next_run_date => d_next_run_date
            );

    dbms_output.put_line(d_next_run_date);
END;
```

The requirements that I have to fullfill need not support timezone. If possible, I would like to use datatype DATE with procedure dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string. However, dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string parameters are of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE. How could I convert from DATE into TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE and avoid that exception?

I noticed that the exception is thrown when a date value that corresponds to summer is passed into parameter return_date_after. So the error might be related to daylight saving time.

database version: 11.2.0.1.0

nls parameters
[image]

Comment: What time zone is your session in (`select sessiontimezone from dual`); and what does `select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual` return?

Comment: Try cast. `select cast (sysdate as timestamp with time zone) from dual;'

Comment: Do you really like to start the jobs in half a year?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? Mine is 12.2.0.1, and on my system your code runs perfectly fine; no error thrown, the procedure prints the next run date correctly.

Comment: However, I see that your two versions (original code and the one you say works) are identical. Did you make a mistake when you posted this - perhaps your code that throws an error is **not** the one you posted as the "existing code"?

Comment: It took me a while to spot that the second return-after date is 2021, while the failing one is 2022. Not sure why you'd use a date so far ahead of start date with a 15-day frequency. There's still no obvious reason for it to error though, and it's unlikely to matter how you generate the argument as it's failing within the package, not in your call to it. It looks like an 11g bug maybe.

Comment: @AlexPoole, session time zone is America/Sao_Paulo.

Comment: @mathguy, I edited the post based on your comments. Actually the two versions are not identical, the value that is passed into parameter return_date_after is different.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to avoid that error by adding time and timezone when casting the characters into TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    d_next_run_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string(
            calendar_string => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=15', 
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('04/06/2021 00:00:00 00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'),
            return_date_after => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/01/2022 00:00:00 00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'),
            next_run_date => d_next_run_date
            );

    dbms_output.put_line(d_next_run_date);
END;
/
```

output

```
15/01/22 00:00:00,000000 +00:00
```